# what is the difference between data descriptors and accessor descriptors?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the documentation of [Object.defineProperty](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on MDN,

They're explaining it very well but I'm unable to understand what is the difference between data descriptors and accessor descriptors?

they're not mentioning anything about them, for example how they're created and from where.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference between an accessor descriptor and a data descriptor is that accessors replace the value and writable configuration flags with get and set functions. [More info on this here](https://itnext.io/enhancing-javascript-objects-with-descriptors-and-symbols-2cdc95e9b422)

Data descriptor

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: true,
  value: 'some value'
});
```

Accessor descriptor

```
Object.defineProperty(obj, 'key', {
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  get() {
    return this.some_value;
  },
  set(data) {
    this.some_value = 'some value';
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Property descriptors present in objects come in two main flavors: data descriptors and accessor descriptors. A data descriptor is a property that has a value, which may or may not be writable. An accessor descriptor is a property described by a getter-setter pair of functions. A descriptor must be one of these two flavors; it cannot be both.

A data descriptor defines `{value: any; writable: boolean;}`

An accessor descriptor defined `{ get(){}, set(value){} }`

You can/have to define one or the other, you can't use getter/setter with writable or some other crossover.

*Both also allow the properites like `enumerable`, etc.*

Answer (score 1):

Three years later, but I hope my answer is useful for you and for anyone else showing up here.

I think that your first question was already well answered. I'll focus on your second one, namely 'how they're created and from where'.

The immediate answer is that the descriptor is created anytime you define a property! And the descriptor is an object itself! The differences between the data property descriptor and the accessor property descriptor are already answered, like I've told you.

In the same MDN article that you posted you can get some hints regarding your second question under the voice 'Description':

> Both data and accessor descriptors are objects. They share the following optional keys (please note: the **defaults** mentioned here are in the case of defining properties using Object.defineProperty())

also:

> If a descriptor doesn't have any of the value, writable, get, and set keys, it is treated as a data descriptor. If a descriptor has both [value or writable] and [get or set] keys, an exception is thrown.

This means that, when you define a property with the `Object.defineProperty()` method, and you omit some or all keys in the `descriptor` object argument of that method, a descriptor need to be created anyway and those missing keys get a default value. But what if you define a property without the `Object.defineProperty()` method? What happens to the descriptor object? It gets created anyway with other default values!

Take a look at this example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N08E3.png)

As you can see, a data descriptor object was created anyway. Also the three properties that I didn't specified (`configurable`, `enumerable`, and `writable`) were added anyway with a default value of `true` (instead they get `false` as a default value if you don't specify them when you create a property with the `Object.defineProperty()` method).

So, as you can see, a descriptor object need to be created anyway!

You can get more info abut this argument at https://javascript.info/property-descriptors

This is what is written about the descriptor object keys when you define a property object in the usual way (bold and italic mine):

> Object properties, besides a value, have three special attributes (so-called “flags”):
> writable – if true, the value can be changed, otherwise it’s read-only.
> enumerable – if true, then listed in loops, otherwise not listed.
> configurable – if true, the property can be deleted and these attributes can be modified, otherwise not.
> We didn’t see them yet, because generally they do not show up. ***When we create a property “the usual way”, all of them are true.*** But we also can change them anytime.

and this is what is written about descriptor object keys when you define an object property with the `Object.defineProperty()` method (again, bold and italic mine) :

> If the [descriptor] property exists, defineProperty updates its flags. Otherwise, it creates the property with the given value and flags; in that case, ***if a flag is not supplied, it is assumed false.***

Hope this helped!

Cheers